# systemctl status returning active even when the service is stopped

Tags: shell, unix, systemctl

I have stopped a systemctl service using below command

`systemctl stop service_name`

but the below command is showing it as active

`systemctl is_active service_name`

I want to know whether the service is stopped or running . How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to achieve this ?

With `systemctl is_active service_name`.

> the below command is showing it as active

So it is active.

If you want to know if a service is *stopping*, you can do `systemctl show -p SubState service_name`.

Comment: I want to know whether the service has successfully started or not. If I stop the service and run `systemctl show -p SubState service_name` then also i am getting `SubState=exited` which is the same output when the service is started.

Comment: What does it mean for a service to be "started"? What does it mean to eb "successfully started"? If a service has "ActiveAfterExit=true", is it "started" after exiting or not? What is the output f `systemctl status`. Why do you stop the service if you want it started. Then finaly, if you want to know if something successfully started, then you should implement an application specific external healthcheck, not check what systemctl says.